# Neural Nets with Pymc3

Tags: neural-network, bayesian, hierarchical, mcmc, pymc3

I am trying to use pymc3 to sample  from the posterior, a set of  single-hidden layer neural nets  so that I  could then convert the model to a hierarchical one, same as in Radford M.Neal's thesis.  my first model looks like this:

```
def sample(nHiddenUnts,X,Y):
    nFeatures = X.shape[1]
    with pm.Model() as model:        
        #priors
        bho = pm.Normal('hiddenOutBias',mu=0,sd=100)        
        who = pm.Normal('hiddenOutWeights',mu=0,sd=100,shape=    (nHiddenUnts,1) )        
        bih = pm.Normal('inputBias',mu=0,sd=100 ,shape=nHiddenUnts)        
        wih= pm.Normal('inputWeights',mu=0,sd=100,shape=(nFeatures,nHiddenUnts))        
        netOut=T.dot( T.nnet.sigmoid( T.dot( X , wih ) + bih ) , who )+bho

        #likelihood
        likelihood = pm.Normal('likelihood',mu=netOut,sd=0.001,observed=Y)

        start = pm.find_MAP()
        step = pm.Metropolis()
        trace = pm.sample(100000, step, start,  progressbar=True)       
        return trace
```

and in the second model hyperpriors are added which are precisions of noise, input-to-hidden and hidden-to-output weights and biases( e.g. bihTau = precision of input->hidden bias ). The parameters for the hyperpriors  are chosen so that they could be broad and also log-transformed.

```
        #Gamma Hyperpriors
        bhoTau, log_bhoTau = model.TransformedVar('bhoTau', 
                                        pm.Gamma.dist(alpha=1,beta=1e-2,testval=1e-4),
                                        pm.logtransform)
        WhoTau, log_WhoTau = model.TransformedVar('WhoTau', 
                                        pm.Gamma.dist(alpha=1,beta=1e-2,testval=1e-4),
                                        pm.logtransform)
        bihTau, log_bihTau = model.TransformedVar('bihTau', 
                                        pm.Gamma.dist(alpha=1,beta=1e-2,testval=1e-4),
                                        pm.logtransform)
        wihTau, log_wihTau = model.TransformedVar('wihTau', 
                                        pm.Gamma.dist(alpha=1,beta=1e-2,testval=1e-4),
                                        pm.logtransform)
        noiseTau, log_noiseTau = model.TransformedVar('noiseTau', 
                                        pm.Gamma.dist(alpha=1,beta=1e-2,testval=1e+4),
                                        pm.logtransform)

        #priors
        bho = pm.Normal('hiddenOutBias',mu=0,tau=bhoTau)        
        who = pm.Normal('hiddenOutWeights',mu=0,tau=WhoTau,shape=(nHiddenUnts,1) )        
        bih = pm.Normal('inputBias',mu=0,tau=bihTau ,shape=nHiddenUnts)       
        wih= pm.Normal('inputWeights',mu=0,tau=wihTau ,shape= (nFeatures,nHiddenUnts))                    
       .
       .         
       .

        start = pm.find_MAP()
        step = pm.NUTS(scaling=start)
```

where bho,who,bin and win are biases and weights of hidden-to-output and input-to-hidden layers.
To check my models 3 to 5 sample points [0,1) was drawn from a one dimensional toy function of the following form

```
def g(x):
     return np.prod( x+np.sin(2*np.pi*x),axis=1)
```

The first model (constant  hyper-parameters) works fine! but when I  sample from the posterior of the hyperparameters+parameters e.g. replace the priors in the first (above)listing with the ones in the second, neither the find_MAP() nor sampling method converges regardless of the number of samples and the resulted ANNs won't interpolate the sample points. Then I tried to integrate hyperpriors into my model one by one. The only one which could be integrated without problem was the noise precision. if I include any of the others then the sampler won't converge to the posterior. I tried this using one 'step function' for all the model variables and also combination of two separate step methods over parameters and hyperparams. In all the cases and with different number of samples the problem was still there.

Comment: I think you should add some more details in which way they "don't work properly", this is rather vague.

Comment: I'll come back to this, but for now, have you considered not optimizing over your hyper priors? Does it work then? Optimizing over hyperpriors especially scale hyperpriors often works poorly because in many cases there is no minimum. For example: Think about the case where you have several normally distributed hidden variables and a scale parameter for the prior. You can make the probability arbitrarily dense by making all the normally distributed hidden variables take on the same value and making the scale parameter smaller and smaller. Let me know if that doesn't make sense to you.

Comment: @JohnSalvatier thank you for your comment. I updated my question to reflect your points! If I don't include hyperparams everything is fine. but I am trying to have a hierarchical model and sample over both params and hyperparams. somthing similar to the one explained in RM. Neal's "Bayesian learning for neural networks".

Comment: It seems that something is wrong with the parameter values of my hyperpriors!

Comment: Can you include something that exactly replicates the data you're passing in as X and Y? Its not clear to me exactly what you're passing in from your description.

Comment: It seems very weird to me that the model would behave differently if you have fixed hyper parameters vs. present but fixed hyper parameters. These should behave identically.

Comment: @JohnSalvatier following corrections worked: 1)No transformation is required in hyperparameters . so directly using gamma or halfNormal  suffices.  2) with the above setting, hyperpriors should be defined over standard deviations.However,  they are defined over  precisions. a broad hyperprior over precision may lead in  very narrow priors over parameters.  with these changes, if metropolis step method is used, the model works fine.Yet, I have trouble applying HMC and NUTS.  Nuts stalls, HMC doesn't converge and crashes if applied on subsets of  model variables. same goes with find_MAP()

Comment: @JohnSalvatier X and  Y are set as follows: np.random.seed(1234);X= np.atleast_2d(np.random.uniform(0,1.,size =3)).T;
Y = np.atleast_2d(g(X)).T

Comment: @JohnSalvatier Could you please change the line 59 in hmc.HamiltonianMC .__init__   from  'scaling = guess_scaling(Point(scaling, model=model), model=model)'  to 'scaling = guess_scaling(Point(scaling, model=model), model=model, vars = vars)' . I guess the missing var parameter causes it to crash if applied on a subset of model.vars!